# How to modify ajax calls or promises chain so that multiple variables (from an array) can be used in separate ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm working on an web app which displays what the predefined Twitch channels are streaming at the moment. The information is sourced from two seperate AJAX calls to the Twitch API.

Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/BzoPBN
**UPDATE:** This codepen now includes a working solution.

I've managed to develop a solution which works... but unfortunately only for one channel.

How to best refactor my ajax calls or perhaps the promises chain so that multiple variables (from an array) can be passed? Ideally the order of the data received from both AJAX methods should be the same.

```
// The solution works only for one channel
var channels = 'monstercat';


// *****How to best refactor the code so that it works 
// for an array of channels as listed below?*****

// var channels = ['monstercat', 'FreeCodeCamp', 'Testing_Channel_01'];


// AJAX number 1
function getChannels(channels) {
  return $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'+channels+'?callback=?');
}


// AJAX number 2
function getStreams(channels) {
  return $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+channels+'?callback=?');
}


// Access data from AJAX call 1 and 2
function processData(channelsData, streamsData) {
  console.log(channelsData);
  console.log(streamsData);
}


// Promises chain
$.when(
  getChannels(channels),
  getStreams(channels)
  )
  .then(function(channelsData, streamsData) {
    processData(channelsData[0], streamsData[0])
  });
```

Comment: Can you relate the `channelsData` and `streamData` somehow? Otherwise are you assured the related channel and stream data will come in the same order? I've had some wine, but it seems like a simple loop could do this.

Comment: Do you think I should be trying to add a loop to the AJAX calls or to the promises chain?  Also, I will not be assured about the order so I will probably have to relate the data. Thank you for your hints.

Comment: Not certain what issue is with `js` at Question?

Comment: I would like to modify the code so that it works for an array of commented out `channels`. At the moment it works just for one channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to develop a working solution using the `map()` and `Promise.all()` methods. Here is the updated code and codepen: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/BzoPBN

```
var channels = ['monstercat', 'FreeCodeCamp', 'Testing_Channel_01'];


// AJAX number 1
function getChannels(channels) {
  var promises = channels.map(
    channel => $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'+channel+'?callback=?')
  );
  return Promise.all(promises);
}


// AJAX number 2
function getStreams(channels) {
  var promises = channels.map(
    channel => $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+channel+'?callback=?')
  );
  return Promise.all(promises);
}


// Access data from both AJAX calls 1 and 2
function processData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}


// Promises chain
Promise.all([
  getChannels(channels),
  getStreams(channels)
])
  .then(processData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to kriskowal's Q library for jQuery. You can pass list of promises as array. Refer to this page : https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery

```
$.when(jQueryPromise1, jQueryPromise2).then(function (result1, result2) {

});

// becomes

Q.all([qPromise1, qPromise2]).spread(function (result1, result2) {

});
```

**EDIT:**
Example for Promise Array

```
function getChannelLinks(channelArray){
    var promiseArray = [];
    channelArray.forEach(function(value, index){
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'+value+'?callback=?', function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        promiseArray.push(deferred.promise)
    });
    return promiseArray;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var channels = ['monstercat', 'FreeCodeCamp', 'Testing_Channel_01'];
    var channelPromiseArray = getChannelLinks(channels);
    // Do something similar for Stream Array
    // var streams = ["stream1","stream2", "stream3"];
    // var streamPromiseArray = getStreamLinks(streams);
    // var promiseArray = channelPromiseArray.concat(streamPromiseArray);
    Q.all(channelPromiseArray).spread(function(results){
        // Get results of everything at one place.
        console.log(results);
    });

})
```

Comment: Would you know how to generate the array of promises? At the moment, I'm passing just one channel to the AJAX calls. I don't know how to pass multiple channels (from the commented out `channels` array) to my AJAX calls.